# MVC4 Install in visual studio 2010 Professional

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

i install visual studio 2010 professional.i install MVC4 but it is not install require SP1 how i install

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: How i install MVC4 in Visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

First, install VS 2010 SP1 from here: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010%20service%20pack%201

Then install MVC4 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: i already install visual studio 2010 .question i install MVC4

Comment: Do you have SP1 installed? Go to Help -> About.

Comment: SP1 stands for "Service Pack 1", it's an update to Visual Studio. click the link in this answer to install it. it is a prerequisite for MVC4 in VS 2010.

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010%20service%20pack%201

Comment: VS 2010 SP1 is individual visual studio like vs 2010 professional